# Optimal control of a damped harmonic oscillator through a lossy, dispersive medium

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, optimization

Say a damped harmonic oscillator is at the far end of a dispersive, lossy medium governed by, say, Debye relaxation. I would like to determine what the optimal arbitrary input waveform is to obtain the maximum instantaneous (not steady-state) amplitude on the oscillator.

If there wasn't dispersion, this would be relatively easy - can't do much better than the solution to the oscillator DE. However, if group velocity is taken into account, [you *can* do much better](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4461).

If one wants to determine the response of an oscillator to some arbitrary known input, it seems like you can build your input with delta functions, [and then use Green functions](https://www.int.washington.edu/users/dbkaplan/228_01/green.pdf) to get the response, maybe with numerical integration in there somewhere.

But I would like to do the *reverse*; determine the "optimal control", subject to some transfer function. Are there some search terms I should be using - or does anyone know of any examples of analogous problems in other fields that might be of use?

Very sorry if this is too open-ended - frankly, I don't understand what I'm doing!